# C#: Reflection: Access property of subclass

Tags: c#, system.reflection

**I am trying to access the property of a subclass through reflection.** But that is not working. How can I get access to all the properties of the subclass?

This is the class where I try to access the properties of the subclass through reflection.
I tried class structure abstract and partial but both are not working.

```
public abstract class FakeDbContext
{
    public FakeDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class, IObjectState
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(FakeDbSet<T>))
                return property.GetValue(this, null) as FakeDbSet<T>;
        }
        throw new Exception("Type collection not found");
    }
}
```

The subclass with the parameters

```
public class MockDbContext : FakeDbContext
{
    private FakeDbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    private FakeDbSet<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    private FakeDbSet<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    private FakeDbSet<BaseContact> Contacts { get; set; }
    private FakeDbSet<Environment> Environments { get; set; }
    private FakeDbSet<Data.Entities.InformationService> InformationServices { get; set; }
    private FakeDbSet<UserEnvironmentConfiguration> UserEnvironmentConfigurations { get; set; }
    private FakeDbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    private FakeDbSet<UserEnvironmentConfigurationSet> UserEnvironmentConfigurationSets { get; set; }

    public MockDbContext()
    {
        Addresses = new FakeDbSet<Address>();
        EmailAddresses = new FakeDbSet<EmailAddress>();
        PhoneNumbers = new FakeDbSet<PhoneNumber>();
        Contacts = new FakeDbSet<BaseContact>();
        Environments = new FakeDbSet<Environment>();
        InformationServices = new FakeDbSet<Data.Entities.InformationService>();
        UserEnvironmentConfigurations = new FakeDbSet<UserEnvironmentConfiguration>();
        Customers = new FakeDbSet<Customer>();
        UserEnvironmentConfigurationSets = new FakeDbSet<UserEnvironmentConfigurationSet>();

        InitData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the private properties you need to use `BindingFlags.NonPublic` using the overload of [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes `BindingFlags` as a parameter.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    ...
}
```